# Rewrite a react class component as a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I try to use a library [Tick](https://github.com/pqina/flip), but it only has a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-flip-demo-txoux?file=/src/Flip.js), which is written in React class component.

```js
import React from "react";
import Tick from "@pqina/flip";
import "@pqina/flip/dist/flip.min.css";

export default class Flip extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._tickRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._tickInstance = Tick.DOM.create(this._tickRef.current, {
      value: this.props.value
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (!this._tickInstance) return;
    this._tickInstance.value = this.props.value;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (!this._tickInstance) return;
    Tick.DOM.destroy(this._tickRef.current);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this._tickRef} className="tick">
        <div data-repeat="true" aria-hidden="true">
          <span data-view="flip">Tick</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'd like to use the library as a Hook component, the following code is what I rewritten:

```js
import Tick from "@pqina/flip";
import "@pqina/flip/dist/flip.min.css";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

interface IFilpProps {
    value: number
}

const Filp: React.FC<IFilpProps> = (props) => {

    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [tickInstance, setTickInstance] = useState<any>();

    useEffect(() => {
        setTickInstance(Tick.DOM.create(ref.current, {
            value: props.value
        }));
        return () => {
            Tick.DOM.destroy(ref.current);
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        tickInstance?.value && (tickInstance.value = props.value);
    }, [props.value])

    return <div ref={ref} className="tick">
        <div data-repeat="true" aria-hidden="true">
            <span data-view="flip">Tick</span>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

outside the component, I have a button, every time I click it adds one:

```js
const [flipSecond, setFlipSecond] = useState<number>(0);
// Omit some not important code
<Flip value={flipSecond}></Flip>
<button onClick={() => setFlipSecond(flipSecond+1)}>+1</button>
```

[The demo which uses class component](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-flip-demo-txoux?file=/src/Flip.js) works fine, but my hook code can't work normally: when I click the '+1' button, the Flip component won't plus 1. Could you help me find out the the reason?

Comment: Putting the instance on a ref instead of state might help.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a ref instead of state to store `tickInstance`.
In general if you want to replace variables that used to be stored in the constructor before, it is recommended now to be stored as refs when rewriting class based components to functional.

```
export default function Flip({value}) {
  const tickRef = React.useRef();
  let tickInstance = React.useRef()


  useEffect(()=>{
    tickInstance.current = Tick.DOM.create(tickRef.current, {
      value
    });

    return () =>  Tick.DOM.destroy(tickRef.current);
  },[])

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (!tickInstance.current) return;
    tickInstance.current.value = value;
  },[value])

  return (
    <div ref={tickRef} className="tick">
    <div data-repeat="true" aria-hidden="true">
      <span data-view="flip">Tick</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-class-component-is-rewritten-as-a-hook-component-9s014)

Comment: This works, but triggers an eslint warning about not having `value` in the dependency list of the first effect. Not sure how to best avoid it, since it clearly should *not* go in the dependency list

Comment: Indeed. I am not sure either how to avoid it. I really like eslint but when dealing with hooks it does not work so nice many times specially when indicating warnings regarding the variables in the dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rewrite for the historic counter

Eg. *Counts the time passed since the start of the millenium in years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds.*

The main thing to take away from here is the use of `useRef()` and how we are using it when creating the `tickInstance` with `Tick.DOM.create()`

```
const FlipClock = () => {

  const tickRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
   const tickInstance = Tick.DOM.create(tickRef.current);

   Tick.count.up("2000-01-01T00:00:00", 
   {format: ["y", "M", "d", "h", "m", "s"],})
   .onupdate = (value) => {
  tickInstance.value = value;
 };
});

return (
    <div ref={tickRef} style={{ fontSize: "3rem" }}>
      <div data-repeat="true" aria-hidden="true">
        <span data-view="flip">Tick</span>
      </div>
   </div>
 );
};

export default FlipClock;
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-flip-demo-forked-ocey9)